# Flex 3 Actionscript Array Subtract function

Tags: arrays, actionscript, subtraction

Can anyone tell me how to compare two arrays and delete the common terms in ActionScript?

Eg:

```
Array1 = [2,4,6,8,10,12]

Array2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

Array1 - Array2 = [12]
```

Comment: Yeah sorry; brain was not in gear when I posted that comment - it was the 'delete common terms' bit that was throwing me.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [ActionLinq](http://actionlinq.org), it is very easy to do set mathematics like this:

```
var array1:Array = [2,4,6,8,10,12];
var array2:Array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];

var subtraction:Array = Enumerable.from(array1)
                        .except(Enumerable.from(array2))
                        .toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter using a custom function.
This is not an optimized way of filtering a difference of arrays, but it'll get the job done.

```
subtraction = Array1.filter(function(item:*, index:int, arr:Array){
  var i:int;
  var l:int;
  l = Array2.length;
  for ( i=0; i < l; i++ )
  {
    if ( Array2[i] == item )
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to knock out all duplicates from an Array then I suggest that you use a Set to make the lookup speed as fast as possible:

```
const a : Array = [ 2, 3, 4 ];
const b : Array = [ 3, 4, 5 ];

// Create a Set for Array 'b' to provide a fast lookup table.
const setB : Object = {};

var prop : *;
for each (prop in b) { 
    setB[key] = true 
};

// Find all values which only belong in Array 'a'.
const uniqueToA : Array = [];
for each (prop in a) {
    if (setB[prop] === undefined) {
        uniqueToA.push(prop);
    }
}
```

If you find yourself doing a lot of work with collections then I would advise you invest in a Collections Framework such as [AS3Commons Collections](http://sibirjak.com/osflash/projects/as3commons-collections/).